# "Unsanitizing" elements within array

Tags: php, arrays

**What I'm doing:** I have a txt file with item #'s in it. I also have a directory of images that have these item #'s as prefixes of their file name but also have a few other string's (delimited by a `-`) after it, and then the file extension (`.jpg`).

**The problem:** The function I have works well, but the resultant array (`$overlap`) needs be in the format that the images originally had, because I'm going to write this array into a CSV file so I can import it. But in order to find the matches, I had to strip the original formatting on the image file names (so `array_intersection()` would work), but now I need to restore it.

Here is the current code:

```
function test() {

    function sanitize_items($value) {
        # Convert to uppercase, remove whitespace, then remove .JPG extension.
        # If the name has a "-", return the part before it.
        $base = basename( trim(strtoupper($value)), '.JPG' );
        $temp = explode('-', $base);
        return $temp[0];
    }

    $file = file('items.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $img = scandir('img');

    $file = array_map('sanitize_items', $file);
    $img  = array_map('sanitize_items', $img);

    $overlap = array_intersect($file, $img);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($overlap); # returns the matches, but not in the format I need.
}
```

This is what `$overlap` currently returns:

```
Array
(
[0] => DEC308A
[1] => DEC308B
[2] => DEC309A
...
)
```

I need it to return the intersections but the way it was before `sanitize_items()` was ran:

```
Array
(
[0] => DEC308A-2020.jpg
[1] => DEC308B-2020.jpg
[2] => DEC309A-2300.jpg
...
)
```

Comment: Are all the strings like `DEC308A` unique in the file or img list? That is, would you ever have both `DEC308A-1234.jpg` and `DEC308A-4321.jpg`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Yes they are unique - there is only one image per item number.

Comment: "but not in the format I need." you mean that it does not return the id and the file extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of applying your sanitize function using `array_map()` (which can't preserve array keys), I would recommend doing a `foreach()` loop on both of the inputs to produce a new array which has the string like `DEC308A` as the *associative array key*, and the original full `.jpg` string as its value. You may then call [`array_intersect_key()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) across them to produce an intersection output which has both the shortened/sanitized string (in the key) and the original (in the value).

```
// Keep this function as it is...
function sanitize_items($value) {
    # Convert to uppercase, remove whitespace, then remove .JPG extension.
    # If the name has a "-", return the part before it.
    $base = basename( trim(strtoupper($value)), '.JPG' );
    $temp = explode('-', $base);
    return $temp[0];
}

$file = file('items.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$img = scandir('img');

// Temporary sanitized arrays:
$file_sanitized = array();
$img_sanitized = array();

// Loop over the input arrays and store them as key => value
// pairs, where the sanitized string is the key
foreach ($file as $f) {
  // Produces $file_sanitized['DEC308A'] = 'DEC308A-2020.jpg';
  $file_sanitized[sanitize_items($f)] = $f;
}
// Same kind of thing for $img...
foreach ($img as $i) {
  $img_sanitized[sanitize_items($i)] = $i;
}

// Now compare for intersection by key
$overlap = array_intersect_key($file_sanitized, $img_sanitized);

//-------------------------------- 
// Note, not sure of your inputs but you might need to reverse the args favoring
// $img_sanitized so you get those resultant values rather than what was in the file...
// $overlap = array_intersect_key($img_sanitized, $file_sanitized);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($overlap);
```

If you really want plain numeric keys at the end rather than strings like `DEC308A`, just call `array_values()` on it:

```
$overlap = array_values($overlap);
```

Comment: Copy/paste errors for 1 & 2.  3 is likely because of the order of arguments in `array_intersect_key()`. See the comment note I added below it about favoring `$img_sanitized`...